# TypeError: '_typedict' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following class:

```
class CData(BigEndianStructure):

  _fields_ = [("x", c_uint),
              ("y", c_uint*10)]

  _pack_ = 1
```

I'm reading file which contains this class:

```
aFile  = open("A_FILE.bin", "rb")
aBytes = aFile.read()
cData  = cast(aBytes, POINTER(CData)).contents
aFile.close()
```

but I'm getting error on the `cast` code line:

```
TypeError: '_typedict' object is not callable
```

What is wrong and how can I handle it ?

Comment: please include the full stacktrace.  please include the imports (what is `cast`? what is `BigEndianStructure`?)

Answer (score 0):

the `cast` should be `ctypes.cast`, like this:

```
cData  = ctypes.cast(aBytes, POINTER(CData)).contents
```